# MySQL Некорректная выгрузка текстовых данных

Tags: java, mysql, кодировка, jdbc

Столкнулся с проблемой на выводе данных из MySQL. Скорей всего проблема в кодировке. Я что-то подобное раньше делал, но уже подзабыл. Можете напомнить что нужно тут сделать?

Вот класс:

```
public void check() {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/sample");
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM peoples");
            while (rs.next()) {                
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
            }

        } catch (NamingException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Вот лог вывода в глазфише:

```
Info:   RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
Info:   ??­?¤¦?? ?® § ???? ¬
Info:   ‚?¤???© ????? «??? ???­?????®?® ­ ¤§®?  ?® ?­????­­?¬ ?­¦?­??­?¬ ?????¬ ¬
Info:   ??­?¤¦??
Info:   ??­?¤¦?? ?® § ???? ¬
Info:   ‘???? «??? ?«?¦?? ???­?????®© ?®¤¤??¦??
Info:   “?? ?«????© ¬ ? §?­®¬
Info:   “?? ?«????© ¬ ? §?­®¬
Info:   ????®­ «?­?© ???­?? ?® ???­???
Info:   ??­?¤¦?? ?® ®?? ­?§ ??? ¬??®??????©
Info:   ‘???? «??? ?® ¬ ?????­??
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [SampleServer] at [/SampleServer]
Info:   ChessmanWorkServer was successfully deployed in 1 379 milliseconds.
```

Вот лог вывода если вместо name указать rating(рейтинг пользователя, колонка в таблице).

```
Info:   Loading application [SampleServer] at [/SampleServer]
Info:   ChessmanWorkServer was successfully deployed in 323 milliseconds.
Info:   RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
Info:   82
Info:   84
Info:   78
Info:   63
Info:   62
Info:   58
Info:   56
Info:   52
Info:   48
Info:   44
```

Сижу тут, грустным взглядом наблюдаю на эти козябры.
Господа, варианты?

Спустя день:
Сделал сервелет вот скрин. Проблема не в кодировке нетбинса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрипт создания таблицы (peoples заменил на workers, точней заного таблицу создал ничего не вышло)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась путем переустановки MySQL c 5.5 на 8.0. Также заменил версию коннектора в сервере glassfish. Благодарю @Alex за старания.

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможно в бд данные хранятся в одной кодировке, а считываются данные в java в другой. Попробуй явно пропертей задать кодировку. что-то вроде

```
properties.setProperty("characterEncoding","cp1251");  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc/sample",properties);
```

А может быть у тебя не локализована среда, в которой вывод идет, так что тоже проверь.

Upd:
Вот так в целом пропертся задается

```
Properties properties=new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user","логин");
properties.setProperty("password","пароль");
properties.setProperty("useUnicode","true");
properties.setProperty("characterEncoding","cp1251");
Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/имяБазы", properties);
```

И в настройках Mysql сервера измени стандартную кодировку latin1 на cp1251- должно помочь

Comment: Как только проверю отпишу.

Comment: Сделал кодировку в нетбине ютф 8 не помогло

Comment: а в MySL? ты через проперти задавал кодировку(на уровне джавы)?

Comment: да. 
stmt.executeQuery("SET NAMES cp1251");
            stmt.executeQuery("SET CHARACTER SET cp1251");

Comment: скинь скрипт создания таблицы peoples

Comment: обновил вопрос, теперь там есть скрипт создания таблицы

Comment: я свой комментарий обновил по поводу изменения кодировки. попробуй применить. сет в бд запросом не решает проблему

Comment: Безуспешно, может дело в драйвере MySQL Для glassfish?

Answer (score 0):

Проверь кодировку в БД. При необходимости поменяй.
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;

Comment: Сегодня как раз сделал. Не помогло.